# Swift how to iterate float

Tags: swift2

I tried to find this in Swift 2 docs, but can't find any info how to iterate floats. New swift iteration style make me crazy =) with dots and etc.

for (i = 0; i < 100; i+=0.5)

how to write it in Swift?

This does not work as it's Double:

```
for _ in 5.0.stride(100.0, by: 0.5) {
}
```

Comment: @EricAya not sure how I will iterate doubles?

Comment: @EricAya You cannot test it in playground but you can test it in a generic project if you go to your Project Target Build Settings and set at Swift Compile version - Use Legacy Swift Language Version to yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the (exact) equivalent of your C-loop using `stride`

**Swift 2**

```
for index in 0.0.stride(to: 99.5, by: 0.5) {
  print(index)
}
```

**Swift 3+**

```
for index in stride(from:0.0, through: 99.5, by: 0.5) {
  print(index)
}
```