# Cannot convert value of type ‘Int’ to expected argument type ‘Double’

Tags: swift, for-loop

I cannot figure out how to convert value of type `Int` to expected argument type `Double` for `mph = kph * 0.6214` in the following code:

```
var mph : Double!
var kph : Float!

print("KPH    MPH")

print("------------")

for kph in 60.stride(to: 130, by: 10) {
    mph = kph * 0.6214
    print("\(kph)     \(mph)")
}
```

How do I program the `for` to produce the desired results?

Comment: cast kph to Double like that: **mph = Double(kph) * 0.6214**

Comment: Note that the kph in the for loop is a different variable from the kph at the top, which never gets set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39774669/2303865

Comment: Thanks, @Leo Dabus. Could you comment on the answers below? Which do you think deserves the check?

Comment: I would answer the same as Vadian so i would accept his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply declare the initial value as literal `Double` (adding `.0`)

```
for kph in 60.0.stride(to: 130, by: 10) {
```

Then the compiler infers the type of the function as `Double` and converts the other literals implicitly.

Comment: Is there a performance benefit to that method over an invocation to Double(:)?

Comment: I guess, `stride` is a generic function, everything the compiler can infer is preferable.

Comment: @T. Benjamin Larsen, Would you agree that Vadian's answer is the most correct answer for this question?

Comment: It's certainly the most elegant. You don't need to ask for permission to accept an answer though. :-D (While I definitely appreciate the gesture it would quickly spam up the place).

Comment: @T. Benjamin Larsen, You gave an excellent critical analysis of my code. I thank you so I wanted to show respect! ;)

Answer (score 6):

For the Double / Int stuff you just need to do Double(Int)*. Seems like you need to use an updated version of stride as well. I believe this is about right:

```
for kph in stride(from: 60, to: 130, by: 10) {
    mph = Double(kph) * 0.6214
    print("\(kph)     \(mph)")
}
```

*although you seem undecided if kph should be a Float or an Int, and the kph your outputting is not the kph you've defined as a Float. It seems likely you might wind up with trouble if your plan is to use this value elsewhere.

Comment: There's also no reason to declare `kph` as a `Float!` before the loop.